# Can oscillators be made from a single supply?

Tags: oscillator

Oscillators such as a Wein-bridge sinusoid or a square wave Schmitt trigger oscillator. Is it possible to bias these so they oscillate above 0V?

Comment: Of course they can.

Comment: @tgun: Don't you mean **below** 0V? If you do, the answer is "yes".

Comment: @EMFields No..as in if I only have a positive rail, can I make a waveform which oscillates around a positive voltage.

Comment: @Andyaka could you give an example of such an oscillator, or how to modify a +ve and -ve rail one? Google revealed nothing.

Comment: @tgun926 isn't that what most oscillators do?

Comment: @PhilFrost I'm not sure. All the waveform generators I've seen (sinusoid, triangle, square) all swing around 0V.

Comment: @tgun926 you mean when you look at a graph of "triangle wave", there's a line through the middle? Or, you have an *actual device* where you've actually measured the DC bias? What about a 555 timer in astable mode?

Comment: @PhilFrost Maybe I wasn't clear in my post - I'm trying to make a sinusoidal and square wave oscillator using op amps. I have made a triangle wave and square wave (physically), and it's DC bias was 0. The op amp was connected to a +15V and -15V rail.

Comment: @tgun926: I'll have an example up for you as an answer in a few minutes.  ~ 13kHz sine wave output centered about 4.5V

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating a single-supply version of a dual-supply circuit is fairly trivial - the key is to generate a pseudo-ground. Take a dual-supply oscillator of your choice. Replace the positive supply with one with twice the amplitude. Instead of a negative supply, ground these points. Now, create a pseudo ground by making a voltage divider with 2 equal resistors of, let's say, 1k to 10k. Buffer the output of the divider with an opamp follower. All of the ground connections of the original circuit get connected to this opamp, and you should be in business.

The buffer amp should be faster than the other opamps, and it should have a fairly high current capability, but other than that it's a straightforward proposition.

Note that the new oscillator output is referenced to pseudo-ground, rather than ground, and the amount of noise and distortion present if you reference it to ground will depend entirely on your ability to generate a clean, stable pseudoground. With this in mind, the lower leg of the voltage divider may profitably be replaced with a zener, or the entire divider with a good voltage reference. The reference does not have to be exactly half the positive supply voltage, but doing this will maximize the voltage swing you can get for the AC value of the oscillator.

Comment: Silly me for only biasing the feedback path and not the remaining ground points of the circuit.

Comment: (+1) wonderful and clear explanation. It would be perfect if you had time to add a schematic to show a beginner exactly what you mean. I wish I could upvote twice!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that works; LTspice circuit list [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5ciwvqyjipasuet/Midpoint.asc):

[image]